# Nginx rewriting with end parameter

Tags: url, nginx, rewriting

How can I rewrite for each page of my website this thing ?

```
http://example.org/page.php?locale=en
```

To

```
http://example.org/en/page.php
```

Parts of my config :

```
   if ($host !~* ^www\.){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org$1;
    }

rewrite ^/([0-9a-zA-Z--]+)$ /$1.php last;
```

Thanks.

Comment: will the locale ALWAYS be available? in the second part of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in the location block

```
rewrite ^/([^/])(/.*) $2?locale=$1&$query_string last;
```

If you have certain locales only it would be less room for errors, you could replace the regex with something like this for example

```
rewrite ^/([en|fr|de])(/.*) $2?locale=$1&query_string last;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, 404 error when I try http://example.org/en/somepage.php on every page

Comment: could you add your config to your question

Comment: I have added the parts can cause problem

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
Rewrite ^/page.php?id=(.*)$ /$1/page.php;
```

Could this work for you?